# How do I remove the vertical line that arises from plotting discontinuous data?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have spent a tiresome amount of time trying to figure out, how to remove the vertical line arising when plotting discontinuous data. In my case I'm trying to plot some data, which diverges towards infinity at a given point. I'm using Python 3.6 with matplotlib's pyplot package.

This code produces the same unpleasant flaw:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100) * 0.09
y = 1 / (x - 5)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show
```

Is there anything I can do to remove that line? What is it, I'm not seeing?

Right now, it feels like I've exhausted my options. I've examined the documentation for matplotlib.pyplot.plot and matplotlib.pyplot.scatter and I am unable to fix this problem, even though it feels like this should be an insanely simple operation (I remember once dealing with this in Maple or MatLab or something similar - there you simply set the argument discont=True to accomplish this).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using here?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot to add the most basic info: I'm using python 3.6 and trying to use the package matplotlib.pyplot.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not discontinuous. You have created a single vector (y) and are asking to plot the entire vector. You can plot individual portions of any vector as long as the size of that vector matches the size of the (x) vector, or create separate vectors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100) * 0.09
y = 1 / (x - 5)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x[:50],y[:50])
plt.plot(x[60:],y[60:])
plt.show()
```

[image]